# Android L Preview Nexus 5 emulator does not start. Shows just black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I am trying Android L Preview with Android Stuido and trying to start Nexus 5 emulator but it only shows black screen and never starts. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: please tell me what you have tried so far?

Comment: For me, Nexus 5 didn't work. So I tried the same with Nexus 4 and it worked.

Comment: For me it was just a small black screen at first. I changed the "Scale" setting to "Auto" and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's happens if you are using Windows machine ,

try the following fixes,

1) deactivate the checkbox "Use Host GPU" within the settings of the virtual device and it started working again.
2) try to set CPU/ABI on "Intel Atom (x86)"

if these doesn't work download genymotion emulators
http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Hey. Thanks for replying. I tried with Nexus 4 emulator. It took some time to start but it worked :-) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You must install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer). Don’t use the Android SDK Manager for installing that.
Because at the moment the SDK Manager gives you HAMX installer version 1.1.0. But to build up Android Lollipop emulator, it requires the latest version of HAMX which is 1.1.1. This can be found in the following link Intel [Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAMX installer)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

if you have others issues means please refer this [link](https://rakitech.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/creating-workable-android-5-0-lollipop-emulator/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using **API 22 : Android 5.1.1** . I was facing the same issue then I downloaded the latest system image from **android sdk manager** to run Nexus 5 emulator.

The System-Image was

- **Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image**

  and
  then selected this system image while creating a Virtual Device in **Android Virtual Device Manager**. Just make sure that you have **checked** the  **store a snapshot** checkbox . Now run your emulator. It will take a couple of minutes.

You will see **android** on the emulator screen for a couple of minutes and then it will run.

Comment: just make sure that you have downloaded all the latest tools.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using GenyMotion and facing the same problem then The one and only reason why it is not starting is because you are using only a single Processor for your emulator..!Try using multiple processors... Start with 2... Also, If it does not work then set your Base Memory to at-least 768MB.

Hope this helps...

Thank You :)